# C# GetElementById missing library

Tags: c#, getelementbyid

I have a problem with a `GetElementById` function.
I was looking for tutorial "how to make auto login" aplication and I noticed everyone is getting submission while typing `.Get...` (screen 1). That's how it look in my aplication (screen 2).
When I try use full function it gets this message (screen 3).
I think there can be problem with missing library or something like that.
[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xgjG.jpg)[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvO0.jpg)[Screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9WQ4.jpg)

Comment: If you click a light bulb on the left (on 3rd screen) does it suggest something?.. Anyway, I don't really understand what happens at 1st screenshot, but it doesn't look like WPF which is on 2nd screenshot

Comment: Screen1 is Web Form, your Screen2 and Screen3 is WPF, they are different..

Comment: I am getting something like this [link](https://gyazo.com/08cf405730509060788b960c86ef104e)
This is the video from screen 1:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgbMUllmgZ4&t=429s)
so how can i GetElementById in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a reference to mshtml:

```
using mshtml;
```

Then in your event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)WebBrowser1.Document;
    IHTMLElement element = document.getElementById("email");
}
```

Comment: It's working! Any option to do the same with shorter syntax or it's only way?

Comment: That's about as short as it gets. :)

Comment: ahh... so what's the main problem with my orginal code? I should use other type of aplication or something like that? The syntax from my orginal code look more easier :/

Comment: The main problem was just that you needed to add a project reference to MSHTML since you are working in a WPF project. The example you found was a Windows Forms project.